# Excel: Converting binary to text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to convert the "1" to text in a separate row listed as "Class". So if it is "1" then it converts to the text (type of crime) associated to the number and is added to "Class" Below is how I want it to look like with the "Class" populated with the type of crime from where there are "1"

| Class | Arson | Burglary | CriminalDamagetoProperty | LockVehicle | Robbery | Theft |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Burglary | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| CriminalDamagetoProperty | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Arson | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| LockVehicle | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Robbery | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Theft | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I've been googling how to do this but there isn't a whole lot of information on this. I know it's possible because I've done this before but I forgot how to accomplish it.

Comment: INDEX/MATCH, or XLOOKUP will do this, what have you tried?

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood last time this could be `=TEXTJOIN("",1,REPT($B$1:$G$1,B2:G2=1))` oh as @ScottCraner Sir said yes with `XLOOKUP()` its more easy.

Comment: it looks like the sample data is the expected output, what is the input data? Thanks

Comment: So the input would look exactly the same with the exception of the Class not being populated. I added a new row and called it "Class". I tried using the XLOOKUP function but am not sure how to make it read the dataset.

Comment: Can there be more than a single `1` in a row? If so, you might find the `FILTER` function useful.

Comment: @dcarranco as I have commented above and as Scott Sir has said, if there is single `1` per row then you could use the `XLOOKUP()` --> `=XLOOKUP(1,B2:G2,$B$1:$G$1)` if not i.e. more than one then use `=TEXTJOIN(" | ",1,REPT($B$1:$G$1,B2:G2=1))` this delimited with pipe, you can change the delimiter to comma or semicolon as per your preference . Also with `FILTER()` it would be like `=TEXTJOIN(" | ",1,FILTER($B$1:$G$1,B2:G2=1))`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above by **[Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)** Sir, using `XLOOKUP()` or with `INDEX()` & `MATCH()` it is possible

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A2` --> This will work as long as there is single `1` per row and will only show the first occurrence of the `1` if more than once.

```
=XLOOKUP(1,B2:G2,$B$1:$G$1,"None")
```

---

Using a dynamic spill array formula : `BYROW()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A2`

```
=BYROW(B2:G8,LAMBDA(m,XLOOKUP(1,m,$B$1:$G$1,"None")))
```

---

If there are more than a single `1` then use either `FILTER()` or `REPT()` with `TEXTJOIN()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A2`

```
=TEXTJOIN(" | ",1,FILTER($B$1:$G$1,B2:G2=1,"None"))
```

---

Or,

```
=TEXTJOIN(" | ",1,REPT($B$1:$G$1,B2:G2=1))
```

[image]

---

Using a dynamic spill array formula : `BYROW()` & `TEXTJOIN()` when there more than single `1` per row. One caveat needs to be added here, i.e. `TEXTJOIN()` function has character limit hence suggested not to use the spill array formula in this scenario, if its within limitation, then there is no issue. For more details you can read **[here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)**.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A2`

```
=BYROW(B2:G8,LAMBDA(m,TEXTJOIN(" | ",1,FILTER($B$1:$G$1,m=1,"None"))))
```

---